# Preventing unauthorised use of components

Tags: c++, oop, sfml

I'm building a component system where an abstract type `Component` is inherited from to make components. So far, I have drawable, physical, movable and other components. All seems to go well, and in the `Game` class I perform the following:

```
void Game::init()
{
    pPlayer->addComponent(pMovable);
}

void Game::processEvents()
{
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        pMovable->moveUp(2.f);

    // etc..

    pPlayer->setVelocity(pMovable->getVelocity());
}

void Game::update()
{
    pPlayer->update(0);
}

void Game::play()
{
    while (pWindow->isOpen())
    {
        // ...
        processEvents();
    }
}
```

So far, the component system is really basic and simple. The player is of type `Object` and whenever I call the player's update function, I also have the Object's update function also called. This should really be automated, but that will change in the future. What the real problem is this:

`pPlayer` can still access `pMovable`'s velocity **even if it has not added `pMovable` as a component**. This is problematic because it means anyone can simply get the velocity from `pMovable` and then plug it into their object without having to add `pMovable` as part of their component. Now, what does tend to happen is that the movement becomes unmanaged since there is no movable component to regulate it. I term this unauthorised use of the component, and I want to develop a way by which a component can 'deny' usage of its functionality to an object it is not owned by. There are many solutions to this problem, and I need one which is efficient and practical for use. Here are mine:

1. Throw an exception if the client attempts to allocate a component function into its own without adding it;
2. Create a system by which objects and components are identified and the component keeps track of the objects it is owned by, and the objects keep track of the components it owns. Because this is a many-to-many relationship, an intermediate class that manages all this would have to be created; it also avoids a circular header inclusion.
3. Have a function NOT part of an object simply 'deactivated'. This would require the use of a boolean like 'componentAdded' and all functions would have to check whether the component was added or not, else the function won't do what it ought to be doing.

If you have other solutions to prevent the unauthorised use of components, please share them as I'm keen to learn from others as to how they implemented/or would implement a component system as I have done here.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. I personally am finding it hard to understand what you're saying about `pMovable`.

Comment: I don't think your answer is helpful. I've stated that `pMovable` is a component, and implicitly a movable component. It has functions which I don't want non-owner objects not to have.

Comment: I agree with @AndyG, an MCVE would be helpful. It's going to be a lot easier for us to understand your requirements if you show a complete example *in code.* You may think you've explained enough *in words,* but there's often a disconnect between what a person thinks they've communicated and what other people have understood.

Comment: I agree with Brian and AndyG - I'm still trying to figure out what's going on. The code you have provided has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent specific classes from inheritance.  It's an all or nothing proposition:  any class inherits from the base or none.

The best you can hope for is to narrow the interface.  For example, instead of allowing decendents of `Object` in a function, you may want to have a class `Stationary_Object` or `Enemy_Object` to refine the interface.  This allows you to write functions that take any `Enemy_Object` and won't take a `Stationary_Object` (like a tree or wall).

**Edit 1:  Cheating with friends**
You can allow member access by declaring the members as private and granting access to specific classes using the `friend` class.  The problem is that the class with data will need to be modified whenever a new type of *friend* is created.  I believe this use of `friend`ship defeats the purpose of reusability.

**Edit 2: detecting ownership**
Let's say we have three classes:

```
class Engine;

class Car
{
  Engine car_engine;
};

class Boat
{
  Engine boat_engine;
};
```

And a function:

```
void Fix_Car_Engine(Engine& e)
{
}
```

There is no method in C++ for the `Fix_Car_Engine` to know that it is fixing a car engine or a boat engine.  The function only knows that it has been given a generic engine to fix (or it only knows about the common Engine stuff of the variable).

This issue can be mitigated by refining or narrowing the interface:

```
class Car_Engine : public Engine;
class Boat_Engine : public Engine;

class Car
{
  Car_Engine diesel_engine;
};

class Boat
{
  Boat_Engine propellor_engine;
};
```

In the above example, the Engine class has two specializations:  `Car_Engine` and `Boat_Engine`.  The `Car` now has a `Car_Engine` member and the `Boat` has a `Boat_Engine`.

The functions can now be created to operate on special engines:

```
void fix_boat_engine(Boat_Engine& be);
void fix_car_engine(Car_Engine& ce);
```

The `fix_car_engine` will now only work with Car Engines.  You could say that it works on any class that has-a Car Engine (as long as you pass the Car Engine member).  Likewise, the `fix_boat_engine` function only operates on Boat Engines.

Given:

```
class Rocket_Engine : public Engine;
```

Also, this specialization prevents a Rocket_Engine from being passed to either function.  The functions require specific engine types.

Comment: I don't want to prevent specific classes from inheriting. I just don't want components to be used by objects who don't own the components in question.

Comment: How does one tell whether object A owns object B?  I can create a structure Car that contains an Engine instance.  How does a function know that the Engine belongs to the car versus a boat?

Comment: @Poriferous objects that don't own a component will not be able to access the component _unless you give it a reference to the component_. So stop giving it the reference. Or are you using global variables? (facepalm)

Comment: @Brett I'm not using global variables, but the function `addComponent()` requires a `Component*` which the Movable component qualifies for since it inherits from Component. @ThomasMatthews I reckon there would be a system by which we can identify who the component is owned by, and what component the object is owning. Although that only establishes the identifications, I don't know whether there is a way to tell whether object A owns object B.

Comment: @Poriferous:  See my Edit 2.  I have given an example of interface specialization.

Comment: @Poriferous you said in your question `pPlayer can still access pMovable's velocity even if it has not added pMovable as a component` - doesn't the `addComponent()` function add the component?

Comment: Yes it does. But what is striking is that `pMovable`'s functions can be accessed by an object that does NOT own the component. I'm trying to find a solution where objects can't utilise the functionality of components they haven't added as a component. The reason for this is to prevent abuse of the system and maintain collegiality among objects that derive from type `Object`.

Comment: @Poriferous so how would an object get a reference to a component it doesn't own? (other than the `addComponent` function, because then it does own it)

Comment: Currently, there is no system whereby an object gets a reference to a component it doesn't own. I do plan to create a system where an object allocates an ID for a component as a reference. Unless you care to elaborate what you mean?

Comment: @Poriferous exactly, then at present, the problem stated in your question doesn't exist, since there is no way an object could access a component it doesn't own.

Comment: /facepalm I can't believe you're saying that! I have the code right in front of me and an object who doesn't own a component CAN access the components' functions. The problem does exist! If I were to comment out the 'addComponent' function (which just so happens to be pushing the component back to a vector of Components internally) then there is still movement because the player is still getting the velocity that changes on key presses. I think this is more of a fault that there is no messaging system nor identification system in the composite system yet.